# Java - Using the "find" command to display or delete a specific record from an access file

Tags: javascript, sql, database

So I've been having trouble getting this Java code working properly. I'm trying to use a "find" function to locate a specific set of information from an access database file (.accdb) and either display or delete it.

I'm not having much luck. Which is puzzling, considering as far as I can tell, the "find" code is also needed for adding new entries to the database, and I can do that without problems. I suspect I've mislabeled something somewhere, frankly.

Below is a snippet of my code, which also shows an example of looking for a specific file identified by the "key" which a user writes into a textbox. Help in solving this annoyance would be appreciated.

```
// Implement the four instance methods *************
    // addNew, delete, update - called from each specific PD class
    // find - used locally by addNew(), delete(), and update().
    /**
     * An instance method to find a record in the database.<br /><br />
     *
     * This is a private method and can only be used locally within objects instantiated from this class.<br />
     * Used by addNew(), delete(), and update().
     *
     * @param String objectType
     * @param String key
     * @return a Anime object
     * @throws NotFoundException
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private Anime find (String objectType, String key) throws NotFoundException, SQLException {

        anAnime = null;

        if (objectType.equalsIgnoreCase ("PlushToys")) {
                // define the SQL query statement using the phone number key
            String sqlQuery = "SELECT Anime, Character, Ability, CanItSpeak, Material, Size " +
                                "FROM PlushToys" +
                                "Where Character = '" + key +"'";

                // execute the SQL query statement
            ResultSet rs = aStatement.executeQuery (sqlQuery);

                // next method sets cursor & returns true if there is data
            boolean gotIt = rs.next();
            if (gotIt) {
                // extract the data
            String Anime = rs.getString(1);
            String Character = rs.getString (2);
            String Ability = rs.getString (3);
            String CanItSpeak = rs.getString (4);
            String Material = rs.getString (5);
            String Size = rs.getString (6);
                // create PlushToy instance & add it to the ArrayList
            anAnime = new PlushToys (Anime, Character, Ability, CanItSpeak, Material, Size);
                rs.close();
            } else {
                    // nothing was retrieved
                rs.close();
                throw (new NotFoundException ("not found "));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

After the SQL-query you need to ask whether the result is empty or not. Therefor you have to count the number of rows in the result. You can do that with something like this:

```
ResultSet rs;
  ...
  int count = 0;
  while(rs.next()) {
    count++;  

  }
```

And when count is zero, than you have no entries in the result and the thing the user is searching for is not in the database.